# Change File Charset to HEX to save space

Tags: filesystems, storage, diskspace

i wounder if i can set the **Charset** of a File to **HEX only**.
If i would be able to do so, will this save Diskspace?
By default each Char will take a lot of space, becourse its encoded with **UTF-8** and this will allow the char to be every char it want to be.
So there must be a way to save it with HEX only, so every char has to be a HEX.
I didn't find any Charset in Notepad++.
Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by _HEX only_?

Comment: Anyway, UTF-8 is super efficient for languages using the latin alphabet (which is almost all european and american contries). And UTF-8 will only take more than 1 byte if needed.